# Display a View when rest of content is empty

Tags: swiftui

I have a view body with logic such as this:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    if someCondition {
      SomeView()
    }
    if anotherCondition {
      AnotherView()
      AnotherView()
    }
    if thirdCondition {
      SomeView()
      AnotherView()
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine to conditionally show elements vertically stacked. However, if none of the conditions are satisfied, the VStack is empty and my UI looks broken. I would like to show a placeholder instead. My current solution is to add a manual check at the end on `!someCondition && !anotherCondition && !thirdCondition`:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    if someCondition {
      SomeView()
    }
    if anotherCondition {
      AnotherView()
      AnotherView()
    }
    if thirdCondition {
      SomeView()
      AnotherView()
    }
    if !someCondition && !anotherCondition && !thirdCondition { // 
      Text("Please select an element.")
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is difficult to keep the condition in sync with the content above. I was hoping there was some sort of view modifier I could use such as:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    if someCondition {
      SomeView()
    }
    if anotherCondition {
      AnotherView()
      AnotherView()
    }
    if thirdCondition {
      SomeView()
      AnotherView()
    }
  }.emptyState { // 
    Text("Please select an element.")
  }
}
```

The closest thing I could find is [this tutorial](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/swiftui-empty-state/), but that requires passing in the condition as well.

Is there a way to build a view modifier like this `emptyState` which doesn't require duplicating the condition logic?

---

I was thinking I could use a ZStack for this:

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {  // 
    // empty state text
    Text("Please select an element.")

    VStack {
      if someCondition {
        SomeView()
      }
      if anotherCondition {
        AnotherView()
        AnotherView()
      }
      if thirdCondition {
        SomeView()
        AnotherView()
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

... but then I run into a different issue where if I'm showing real content (e.g. `SomeView()`) but it's not large enough, I could see both `SomeView()` and the empty state text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one implementation using `GeometryReader` & it's named `emptyState`:

```
extension View {
    func emptyState<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(EmptyStateModifier(placeHolder: content()))
    }
}

struct EmptyStateModifier<PlaceHolder: View>: ViewModifier {
    @State var isEmpty = false
    let placeHolder: PlaceHolder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            if isEmpty {//Thanks to @Asperi
                placeHolder
            }
            content
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { reader in
                        Color.clear
                            .onChange(of: reader.frame(in: .global).size == .zero) { newValue in 
                                isEmpty = reader.frame(in: .global).size == .zero 
                            }
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this one is most close to the requirements in question, the only thing I would correct is to use `if isEmpty { placeHolder }` instead of opacity, because set opacity to 0 does not remove placeholder from a view, so ZStack might take more space than it would having only `content` that is not desirable the initial question description. But in general - my vote is here.

Comment: I usually try to minimize `GeometryReader` usage, but because this is inside a `.background()` and it's only used to add a helpful message to the user, this is perfect. Great solution, thanks!

Comment: `onAppear` is only called the first time the `Color.clear` appears. I was able to fix it by adding this right after that: `.onChange(of: reader.frame(in: .global).size == .zero) { newValue in isEmpty = reader.frame(in: .global).size == .zero }`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a long chaining condition, you can handle it with `switch{}`, then use the benefit of `default` to display the placeholder when 0 condition is met(stack is empty or no selection)

```
@State var selected = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        switch selected {
        case "a":
            SomeView()
        case "b":
            AnotherView()
        case "c":
            ThirdView()
        //this default will show up
        //when there is no selection
        //and when the stack is empty meaning that all the above
        //conditions did not meet
        default:
            Text("Please select an element")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer which may fit your needs better than mine. Switch statements are very underused in situations like this

Comment: More than one of the conditions in the original question might be true, but a switch statement only selects one.

Comment: You are right @vacawama, but I believe if his conditions will not exceed too much number, might just put another condition in; if two are selected, result = “1/2”, case “1/2” to handle multiple selection. However, I trust there will be a better solution here.

Comment: @vacawama: is correct. The whole crux of the problem is that multiple conditions could be true. I don't want to repeat any of the condition logic, so while a good suggestion, I don't think `switch` will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward, officially supported way of telling what the return value of a view builder contains.

It is more sensible to handle this at the model layer than in your view. Each of your conditions are part of your model. These should be wrapped up into a single value type, and you can use the presence or absence of that (or an internal calculated value of that, depending on your requirements) to inform what to put in the stack. For example:

```swift
struct Model {
    let one: Bool
    let two: Bool
    let three: Bool
}

struct MyView: View {
    let model: Model?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch model {
            case .some(let model):
                if model.one {
                    Text("One")
                }
                if model.two {
                    Text("Two")
                }
                if model.three {
                    Text("Three")
                }
            case .none:
                Text("Empty")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm assuming here that there is no valid `Model` which doesn't contain any of the values, that would be when it is set to nil)